# How to get deployment name in all namespaces with specific secret used/containing specific text on the deployment yaml?

Tags: jquery, bash, kubernetes, grep, find

I've tried using grep but only secret name showing up, kindly help please , thank you

`kubectl get secret --all-namespaces -o yaml | grep <secretname>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have secrets mounted as volumes, you can could use [custom columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/#custom-columns):

```
kubectl get deploy -A -o=custom-columns=DEPLOYMENT:.metadata.name,SECRETS:.spec.template.spec.volumes[*].secret.secretName
```